# Rviz 2D estimated pose configuration

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

Regarding to the rviz 2D pose estimation, does anyone have an idea of the yaw angle or direction of robot facing every time we relocate robot position with it?
Is it possible to set the yaw angle to my desired angle?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105136/rviz-2d-estimated-pose-configuration/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you initialize the pose you click on the position and drag the direction that you want to initialize the heading.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2